# What are the effects of setting AngularJS $location html5mode.requireBase = false

Tags: angularjs, html

What are the effects of setting `html5Mode.requireBase = false`?

I don't want to the base tag to my site's header template which has many other parts than just the angular app, but it isn't clear what the impact will be if I don't while using the $location service:

[from the AngularJS docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/guide/$location)

> Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. Angular requires you to specify the url base in the head of your main html file (`<base href="/my-base">`) unless `html5Mode.requireBase` is set to `false` in the html5Mode definition object passed to `$locationProvider.html5Mode()`. With that, relative urls will always be resolved to this base url, even if the initial url of the document was different.

Comment: the quote in your question answered the question.  Are you just searching for clarification here?  Without a `<base >` tag, the initial URL will need to match exactly in every instance, making relative URLs relative to the *server* instead of relative to other pages within the *app*.  this means your server rewrites will have to be well planned, and you could experience unnecessary page reloads.